# Images takes so much time to load in j2me mobile application

Tags: image, java-me, loading

I have used below code to fetch image from server. I have 60 different images placed on server. I have urls of all those images. By using while loop I am getting all these images but it's taking so much time to load image from server.

What can I do to get these images as fast as possible?

```
 public Image getImagefromURL(String imageURL) {
    DataInputStream is = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Image img = null;
    try {
        HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(imageURL);
        int len = (int) c.getLength();

        if (len > 0) {
            is = c.openDataInputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[len];
            is.readFully(data);
            img = Image.createImage(data, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}
```

And also one thing is happening that when I fetch first image, application is confirming me like "Application wants to connect to [URL of image location] using airtime. IS it ok to use airtime?" here I want to hide my path of image location. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the image, the longer it will take to load it. Make sure your PNG images are compressed with a tool, for example, [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/).

You can also add a local cache on the application side using RMS.

And a last tip... You should not rely on `HttpConnection.getLength`, it might come as zero even when there is data to be read.

Comment: Can u please tell me what if I have images of 3KB & its of .jpg not png? I hope so there is not any problem if i use jpg images because size of .jpg image is smaller than .png images.

Comment: PNG works for sure with MIDP because it is required by the specification, jpg might not.

Comment: You should try to use smaller image files. According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/databaserms-156896.html "The MIDP specification requires devices to reserve at least 8K of non-volatile memory for persistent data storage."